# Footer is sticking to bottom = good, but main content has scrolls as if footer is fixed = bad

Tags: html, css, scroll

Check my link below. I have my footer stick to the bottom of the screen if you have a large screen, but now if you are on a smaller screen, there is a scroll bar that appears before the footer. Why is this?

http://boldstyle.allthingswebdesign.com/something.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem Lies in the static height and width values of your `DIV` containers.

`CSS:container` is at 1024px. you might want to back this off to 1000px, since most browsers at 1024px will add a horizontal scrollbar to compansate for the very thin 1-2px window border. If your design wont allow for this, you can change `overflow:auto` to `overflow:none`.

`CSS:main` has a static height. Do the same thing as above if the content extends past this height to disable the vertical scrollbar.

Comment: I didn't see an explicit height for #main

Comment: in `styles.css`, `#main` has `overflow:auto`.. `#leftmain` has the static height. as a descendent object it inherits the parent attributes. You may want to get both firebug and webdeveloper plugin for firefox.. it helps debug these things..

Comment: I have them. Overflow:auto on #main is so that the #main div wraps around it's child divs. Now if i change the height of #leftMain, #main will automatically be at least as tall as #leftMain correct.